# snmp_exporter fail to generate snmp.yml

Tags: generator, net-snmp, exporter

I have been trying to configure Prometheus to collect SNMP information and then send that data to Grafana. my problematic configuration to generate the generator.yml file for snmp.yml fails.

I I guess my main problem is that when I reference Huawei MIBs in the generator.yml file, I can only reference part of the MIBs,the rest cannot be referenced, so the OID cannot be searched, resulting in the inability to generate the configuration file.

Does anyone know how I should go about doing this? Or have any experience with generator files or Huawei MIBs?

Here is a screenshot of the software error report.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlxEJ.png)